# Swift control flow with stride

Tags: swift, control-flow, stride

What is the difference between two stride function?

`stride(from:to:by)` & `(from:through:by)`

While go through the tutorial, [Control flow with stride](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120) i found that two types of stride function as per my knowledge both working like a same, i don't know what is the difference between them hence anyone can explain?

**Use the stride(from:to:by:)**

```
let minutes = 60
let minuteInterval = 5
for tickMark in stride(from: 0, to: minutes, by: minuteInterval) {
    // render the tick mark every 5 minutes (0, 5, 10, 15 ... 45, 50, 55)
}
```

Using stride(from:through:by:) instead:

```
let hours = 12
let hourInterval = 3
for tickMark in stride(from: 3, through: hours, by: hourInterval) {
    // render the tick mark every 3 hours (3, 6, 9, 12)
}
```

Comment: Change `to` to `through` in the first example and change `through` to `to` in the second. Note the difference. And read the documentation. Note the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stride(from:through:by:)`:

> Returns the sequence of values `(self, self + stride, self + 2 * stride, … last)` where *last* is the last value in the progression **less than or equal to end**.

`stride(from:to:by:)`:

> Returns the sequence of values `(self, self + stride, self + 2 * stride, … last)` where *last* is the last value in the progression **that is less than end**.

Notice the difference in **bold** text.

It's the difference between a closed range like `[0...10]` and an open range like `[0..<10]`.